# Instance of 'Future<dynamic>' not giving data to string flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, error-handling, syntax-error, geocoding

I'm trying to get city name from coordinates using flutter geocoding library, but it give output in form of "Instance of 'Future'" instead of city name. Code in the screenshot. please help me here.

[Screenshot with code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5C1xL.png)

i'm trying to get solution from this issue.

Comment: Post code that people can copy+paste to reproduce your problem, not screenshots of code.  Also, see [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/) and the [Dart asynchronous programming codelab](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, you can use `await` like this:

```dart
String cityName = await GeocodingPlatform.instance.placemarkFromCoordinates(latitude, longitude).then((value) => value.first.locality);
```

Or you can use `then` like this:

```dart
GeocodingPlatform.instance.placemarkFromCoordinates(latitude, longitude).then((value) {
  String cityName = value.first.locality;
  // do something with cityName
});
```